# Does cross domain tracking in Google Analytics require referral exclusions for subdomains?

Tags: google-analytics

I have 3 websites. One that I host in Azure and two that are hosted by Hubspot.

```
https://example.com
https://blog.example.com
http://info.example.com
```

I have set up cross domain tracking using the [Official Linker](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker) plugin. 
My analytics for each of these domains looks like this.

```
            main site
            ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x', 'auto', { 'allowLinker': true });
            ga('require', 'linker');
            ga('linker:autoLink', ['https://blog.example.com/', 'http://info.example.com/']);
            ga('send', 'pageview');

            blog site    
            ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x', 'auto', { 'allowLinker': true });
            ga('require', 'linker');
            ga('linker:autoLink', ['https://example.com/', 'http://info.example.com/']);
            ga('send', 'pageview');

            info landing pages    
            ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x', 'auto', { 'allowLinker': true });
            ga('require', 'linker');
            ga('linker:autoLink', ['https://example.com/', 'http://blog.example.com/']);
            ga('send', 'pageview');
```

From reading the linker plug in documentation, one of the lines says

*Important: for cross-domain tracking to work properly, you must ensure all domains are included in the Referral Exclusion list as described in the cross-domain tracking guide.*

And it links to [The referral exclusions documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830)

In here it states 
*When you initially set up your Analytics property, your domain is automatically added to the referral exclusion list. As a result, you shouldn't see self-referrals if you have a web property that tracks multiple subdomains.*

So does this mean I have my analytics set up correctly? I'm logged into analytics and I'm on my main `example.com` property. But I see no way to add an additional URL to track. Currently these sites are all set up as different properties under a single account.

And if I do have them set up correctly, is there anything else I need to do to make sure that users who go from `https://example.com` to `https://blog.example.com` are counted as a single session and not as multiple sessions? I want to be able to see user flow because we have a lot of users who bounce back and forth between the main site and the blog and I want to make sure these users are counted as a single session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub-domain tracking is automatic as long as you have specified your `cookieDomain` as `auto`. You can read more about that here: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/cross-domain-tracking-across-subdomains/

Having done so, you won't require any additional tracking for users between your main site and blog. Make sure you have also included the hostname (via View filter) so that you can also see which subdomains your users are visiting, and also include separate views for each subdomain so that you can see traffic for specific subdomains.